# How to Fetch function using string?

Tags: python

I want to fetch function with function name string 
eg.

```
class test(object):
  def fetch_function():
    print "Function is call"

 #now i want to fetch function  using  string 
 "fetch_function()"
```

Result should be: Function is call

Comment: You could use eval: `eval("fetch_function()")` It's not too safe tho, it opens a route for many hackers.

Comment: @ Markus Meskanen : thanx for answer but my issue is that string fix "fetch_function()" i dont want to make any change in that in that case your solution is not work.

Comment: @Heroic You should then clarify your question. What shouldn't be changed? If the string must just stand in your code as it does currently there can't be done very much

Comment: I have already mention in my question that i want to fetch using string "fetch_function()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval()`:

```
eval("fetch_function()")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would leave the `()` from `fetch_function()` you could use `getattr` which is in my opinion safer than `eval`:

```
class Test(object):

    def fetch_function():
        print "Function is called"

test_instance = Test()
my_func = getattr(test_instance, 'fetch_function')

# now you can call my_func just like a regular function:
my_func()
```

Comment: And if you need to call the method only once, there's no need for the variable: `getattr(inst, "fetch_function")()`

Comment: @rednaw : Thanx for your answer ,but i cant leave ().

Answer (score 0):

As said eval is not safe, you could use a dict to map a function to a string and call it

```
class test(object):
  dict_map_func = {'fetch_f': fetch_function}
  def fetch_function():
     print "Function is call"


test.dict_map_func['fetch_f']()
```